# Why is there margin before the image?

Tags: css

I have not put any margin on top of the logo image but still there is gap. I don't understand why. The page is live at http://goo.gl/jNbFp9

My markup:

```
<header>
<img src="images/home-layout_04.jpg" alt="">
</header>
```

My CSS:

```
body {
background-color: #d2d1d0;
background-image: url(images/home-layout_02.jpg);
background-repeat: repeat-x;
background-position: center top;
}
header { width: 984px; margin: 0 auto; text-align: left;}
header img { float: left; margin: 0; padding: 0;}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add `margin: 0px;` to the `body`

this was the missing part, i tried it on Google chrome inspect element and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

try this in **in body:**

```
margin-top:0px;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your body has a `margin: 8px;`. U could use a [reset.css](http://meyerweb.com/eric/tools/css/reset/)

Answer (score 0):

you have `margin:8px;` on your body style

add this in your body css styling

`margin:0px !important;`

Answer (score 0):

You can use any one of these,

http://www.cssreset.com/

it will help you have the same rendering in all browsers and avoid this kind of problems